# Continuity of Multilinear Maps

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Total Derivative and Multilinear Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65686/total-derivative-and-multilinear-functions)

I was trying to figure out why a multilinear map on a finite-dimensional vector space is continuous...however I was stuck in the middle; I got that

$$ \vert\vert f(x,y)\vert\vert \leq M\sum_{i,j}\vert x_{i}y_{j} \vert $$

but cannot figure out what to do next.

Comment: I found what I was looking for here:                         http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65686/total-derivative-and-multilinear-functions

Comment: I assume you speak to the inequalities discussed therein as opposed to the question of continuity. Which, while connected, is distinct from that of differentiability.... in any event, nice find.

Comment: @EvanAad Not sure about your claim on :components" see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/393322

Comment: @TomCollinge: Quite right! I've removed my comment. Thanks!