# Differential of Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

I have a function $f(a)=\langle a,w \rangle$. If I do a derivative to $a$, it is true that $\frac{d}{da}\langle a,w \rangle=w$?

Comment: How is this derivative defined?

Comment: differential to a

Comment: If you remember that $a$ is a vector, then $f(a) = \langle a,w\rangle = w^\top a$, and the derivative (as a linear mapping) is in fact $w^\top$ (i.e., the vector $w$ turned on its side). The *gradient* $\nabla f$ is the vector-valued function $\nabla f = w$.

Comment: I think, it is true If $a,w\in \mathbb{R}^n$. But, What happen in larger space, that is Hilbert space? Can it still be held?

Answer (score 0):

The inner product with respect to a fixed vector $w$ is itself a linear functional,so its total derivative is itself.Given a vector $u$,its evaluation at a unit vector $v$ gives us the directional derivative at $u$ along that vector.But what you have written in the question doesn't make much sense.You need to realize that you are dealing with vectors here,not real numbers.The basic idea of derivative is finding the best linear approximation to a function.You can of course,vary both $a$ and $w$ to get a bilinear form.See here on differentiation of multilinear forms :-

[Total Derivative and Multilinear Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65686/total-derivative-and-multilinear-functions)

Comment: What if we replace $d/da$ with $\nabla_a$?

Comment: That is usually taken to mean the total derivative at $a$.Take care to note that this is not a real number or a vector,but is a linear map,which,in this case,is the inner product itself.If you now evaluate this linear map at a vector $v$ it gives you the rate of change of the field at $a$ along $v$.This means the rate of change of the field if you walk from the point $a$ along a vector $v$.Evaluation of this is easy,you just compute $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+tv)-f(a)}{t}$,which is called Gateaux derivative.If $f$ is linear,this limit is just $f(v)$,which is the total derivative evaluated at $v$.

Comment: The total derivative is often called the Frechet derivative in this regard,usually if you are doing the calculus on Banach spaces.